# Doubt in Hoffman and Kunze Linear Algebra Section 8.5

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, normal-operator

Here is the proof from the book I was reading

[image]

Now, I know about linear transformations and how in its matrix representation , the columns are coordinates of the image of basis vectors in the transformation. I don't know how and why but today while reading this proof I thought of working this proof out and it turned out that matrix multiplication doesn't make sense to me anymore.It is written that $T \alpha_1 = A_{11} \alpha_1$ . Now this makes sense  since first column is the coordinate of image of first basis vector. But if I go by explicit matrix multiplication, it turns out be something else and I got confused .Basically how to prove that this is correct by explicit matrix-multiplication?? This might too stupid to ask but I am badly stuck.

Here is what I mean by explicit multiplication:

[image]

Comment: Are you remembering that $A$ is assumed to be **upper triangular**? That means the only nonzero entry in the first column is the first one. Your question would be easier to answer if you **showed your work** when you say “If I go by explicit matrix multiplication, it turns out to be something else.” Show us why you think that.

Comment: Yea sure. Also, yes I know that $A$ is upper triangular

Comment: @symplectomorphic I added what u asked. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making several category errors, all based on confusing abstract vectors with their coordinate representations given a certain basis.

First, $T\alpha_1$ is a vector in the abstract vector space $V$. It is *not* necessarily a column vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus your first equation $T\alpha_1=A\alpha_1$ is already an error. You cannot multiply the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and the *abstract* vector $\alpha_1$; the right side of your equation is simply nonsense. You are confusing the vector itself with its coordinate representation.

You *can*, however, multiply $A$ and the *coordinate representation* of $\alpha_1$ in the given basis, which is just the column vector $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)^T$. This is your second error: you represented $\alpha_1$ using arbitrary coordinates $x_i$ when in fact the coordinates should be $x_1=1$ and $x_i=0$ otherwise, because $\alpha_1$ is part of the basis. When you represent $\alpha_1$ correctly in coordinates, the product is the vector $(A_{11}, 0, \ldots, 0)^T$, which is indeed $A_{11}$ multiplied by the (correct) *coordinate representation of* $\alpha_1$.

But all of this is overkill. What you need to recall is that the numbers in the first column of $A$ tell you the coordinates of the abstract vector $T\alpha_1$ with respect to the given basis. (There is a theorem in the book that says this.) Since $A$ is upper triangular, the only nonzero coordinate is $A_{11}$, which tells you that the abstract vector $T\alpha_1$ is just $A_{11}\alpha_1$, as desired.

Comment: I know about the theorem u mentioned but not from the book.I know it is overkill too. LOL , I did wrongly assume about $\alpha_1$.  But the $x_i$ were not coordinates in basis. They were representing $\alpha_1$ although that was wrong too. Your last para is perfectly fine to me . It's just I am was not able to imagine this to be true . I will try searching the theorem in the text book. Thanks :)

Comment: But, why are u multiplying the coordinates with $A$. Can u elaborate on that??The second para.

Comment: If you don’t understand what I wrote then you don’t understand anything in the first half of this book and you need to go reread the book.

Comment: You also cannot write “let $\alpha_1=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$”, which is yet another error I did not point out explicitly. As I already said, $\alpha_1$ is an **abstact vector** in an **abstact finite-dimensional vector space $V$**. You cannot assume it is *equal* to a column vector. It could be a polynomial, a matrix, a function....... You can, however, *represent* it with a coordinate vector. When you do that, you get $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)^T$.

Comment: I found the theorem. Thanks a lot for your help. I need to be more careful :(